# Executing update query inside loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

```
   cmd = New SqlCommand("select enrollment,total_fee,discount,net_fee from stu_dtl", openConnection())
        '  dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        adpt = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        adpt.Fill(ds, "stu_dtl")
        dt = ds.Tables("stu_dtl")
 For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
              cmd = New SqlCommand("update stu_dtl set net_fee = '" & (Val(dt.Rows(i).Item("total_fee")) - Val(dt.Rows(i).Item("discount"))) & "' where enrollment = '" & dt.Rows(i).Item("enrollment") & "'", openConnection())
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
```

when I execute this code for more than 150 records "Nothing happens"......what am i doing wrong??is there any other way to update??

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you don't need any of that code. Just creating  a SQL update query and doing an ExecuteNonQuery would do the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are doing wrong. But try this code. If an error occur it ensure rollback of the database. Note that I assume that the datatype of the `net_fee` and `enrollment` columns are `Integer`.

```
Using connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("TODO: Set connection string.")

    Dim table As DataTable = New DataTable("stu_dtl")
    Dim [error] As Exception = Nothing

    Using command As SqlCommand = connection.CreateCommand()
        command.CommandText = "SELECT [enrollment], [total_fee], [discount], [net_fee] FROM [stu_dtl];"
        Using adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
            adapter.Fill(table)
        End Using
    End Using

    Using transaction As SqlTransaction = connection.BeginTransaction()
        Try

            Dim net_fee As Integer = 0
            Dim enrollment As Integer = 0

            For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows

                net_fee = (CInt(row.Item("total_fee")) - CInt(row.Item("discount")))
                enrollment = CInt(row.Item("enrollment"))

                Using command As SqlCommand = connection.CreateCommand()
                    command.CommandText = "UPDATE [stu_dtl] SET [net_fee] = @net_fee WHERE [enrollment] = @enrollment;"
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@net_fee", net_fee)
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enrollment", enrollment)
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using

            Next

            transaction.Commit()

        Catch ex As Exception
            [error] = ex
            transaction.Rollback()
        End Try
    End Using

    If (Not table Is Nothing) Then
        table.Dispose()
        table = Nothing
    End If

    If (Not [error] Is Nothing) Then
        Throw [error]
    End If

End Using
```

**Edit**

Come to think of it, you might want to change the `net_fee` column to a [computed column](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). The formula would simply be `([total_fee] - [discount])`.

Comment: computed column is certainly a better option....still couldn't figure out why the query didn't work. anyways thanks for help